# refresh page only once to get new value from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I make countdown timer from 00:60 to 00:00.
when the timer hit 00:00, I want to refresh the page only once to get new value from database.
Is there anyway how to do it?
 
In my case, when the timer hit 00:00, the page will keep refresh.

Comment: Without the code that gives the unintentional result in your case.. it is going to be hard for us to tell what is happening.. Please add the relevant code to your question (ideally stripped to the bare essence).

Comment: use ajax to load content without refreshing page..

Comment: could you share code snippet?

Comment: call jquery ajax ($.ajax) asynchronous request to refresh the page only once with new values from database, when countdown timer hit 00:00.

Answer (score 0):

Use headers in your web page...

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
</head>
```

You can also use timeout with javascript.